# C++ SFML with Command Line

Tags: c++, cmd, sfml, atom-editor

I hope I'm asking this in the right section, because I'm kind of new here :)
I would like to use Atom (Github's Text Editor) and make some C++ SFML games. Thing is, I simply have no idea how to do that.
I tried searching everywhere for hours and couldn't get it done.
I downloaded MinGW and couldn't compile the file (tried by typing g++) and I simply can't succeed.
It would be really helpful if someone could tell me how to compile C++ with SFML step by step (Getting the compiler, linking the libraries (or however that step is called) etc...)

Thank you so much and have a great day.

Comment: First thing first: what OS are you running on? Things are different from OS to OS. I suppose you're on Windows, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows 8.1, sorry I didn't mention.

Comment: http://www.sfml-dev.org/ Here you can probably find a solution, there are awesome tutorials.
Also you can find alot of Youtube videos about setting up sfml.

Comment: There are only tutorials about setting it up with an IDE like CodeBlocks, not with command line

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use Atom? I suggest you try Visual Studio 2013 - Intellisense is incredibly smart and helpful, it instantly finds both syntax and logic bugs. Atom does none of that.

Later, I would recommend you get a full version of Visual Studio (if you're a student, for example, you might get it for free) and Visual Assist X by Whole Tomato - a tool I couldn't work without :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to compile sfml on command prompt here is how I would do it.
I have windows 10 and use MinGW 64 bit 8.1.0

```bash
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o -IC:/SFML-w64/include -DSFML_STATIC -O3 -g -Wall -m64 && g++ main.o -o run.exe -LC:/SFML-w64/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
# if you dont want command prompt to show up just add -mwindows and remove -g and -Wall
```

also make sure you have MinGW/bin as a path variable by going to control panel - system - advanced settings - environment variables - on the bottom section look for path - press edit - press add and put in your path to MinGW/bin eg: C:/MinGW/bin